# Digitally signing a cxfreeze windows executable?

Tags: python, windows, cx-freeze

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Outputed py2exe exe won't run only when signed: ImportError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198431/outputed-py2exe-exe-wont-run-only-when-signed-importerror)

I am making a program using Python 3.2. I use cxfreeze to turn the scripts into an executable. The frozen executable runs fine when run without changes. When I tried to sign the executable using **`signtool.exe`**, the exe raises `ImportError`. Is there a way to digitally sign a frozen python3 executable?

Thanks!.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED The question (and the provided solution) in the mentioned link are related to python 2.x. py2exe and pyinstaller are not avaiable for python 3.x. Thanks

Comment: still they seem to work the same way. And if you read through the linked topic you will see why exactly that approach does not work. It is because `signtool` basically corrupts the overlay/payload that the stub needs to run the Python code.

Comment: I understand that the problem is same, but not the solutions since the [pyinstaller](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7199367/538850) solution won't work with python3. So I thought posting a separate question for python3 would be appropriate. Anyway, thanks for the link and explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/cx_Freeze.html):

> There are three different options for producing executables as well.
>   **The first option is the only one that was available in earlier
>   versions of cx_Freeze, that is appending the zip file to the
>   executable itself.** The second option is creating a private zip file
>   with the same name as the executable but with the extension .zip. The
>   final option is the default which is to create a zip file called
>   library.zip and place all modules in this zip file.

It is evident why this would fail, when reading the (in my opinion duplicate) topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198431). Different version of the language, yes. Different tool, yes. Different approach, no! It is evident from the error you get that you are using that first option and signtool will interfere with the payload.

Comment: Using the third option solved the problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, signtool.exe is only there to sign .NET based app. Since your app is not .NET based, this failure (exception) takes place.

Comment: _signtool_ doesn't only sign .NET binaries. Your confusion might come from the fact that it ships with the .NET SDK, however it also comes with the Windows SDK.

Comment: Sorry about this guys! both of you are right. Thanks to correct this. :-)